# What is the difference between "I have been looking for you" and "I have looked for you"?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

I am facing an unfortunate complication while studying the present perfect and present perfect continuous tenses.
I can't understand the difference between some of their parts.
What is the difference between *I've been looking for you all day* and *I've looked for you all day*?
The point is, which should I use when I find my friend?
Because they both seem to be finished when I have found my friend, they should not.

Answer (score 2):

- I have looked for you

An hour ago I briefly peeked out the window to see if I could see you.

- I have been looking for you

I walked around the neighborhood for 20 minutes trying to find you.

Answer (score 0):

People may disagree with me on this, but the "all day" in your example defines a span of time, and thus the simple present perfect is inapt. The preferred tense would be the continuous:

**I have been looking for you all day.**

Comment: Not the best choice, but often used in this context.